# Undefined reference error while compiling

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, header

I'm trying to compile a project that has multiple *.c files and *.h file when I type the following command:

```
$gcc -c -I ../hdr main.c gestic.c menu.c
```

the hdr folder is where the *.h files are located, the .o files are created but when I try to link them using the command:

```
$gcc -o main.o gestic.o menu.o
```

I see errors

```
gestic.c:(.text+0x..): undefined reference to functions that are declared in *.h files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$gcc -Wall -c -I../hdr -o main.o main.c
$gcc -Wall -c -I../hdr -o menu.o menu.c
$gcc -Wall -c -I../hdr -o gestic.o gestic.c
$gcc -Wall -o myprogram main.o menu.o gestic.o
```

Using a Makefile is very common for this task

example (untested) Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -I../hdr 

all: myprogram

myprogram: main.o menu.o gestic.o
 $(CC) -o $@ $^

gestic.o: gestic.c
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

main.o: main.c
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

menu.o: menu.c
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ gcc main.o gestic.o menu.o
```

-o filename: Place output in filename

Comment: I did but still the same issue

Comment: There is a function in header files has not been implemented. Show me the entire error output, please.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly header files are not included, secondly you might use the function that doesn't contain the definition.

The message undefined reference to 'function_name' implies that of all the object files you're giving to the linker, none of them has a definition for function_name. That means that either

You're not linking with *.o
*.c (as compiled) does not contain a definition for function_name -- by 'as compiled' I mean with all of the various preprocessor options you use on it.

here -`Iinclude/`

try,

```
gcc -c file.c -I<include_dir>
```

If you compile more files better to have makefile to create the objects of those files, link those objects along with header.

**Sample makefile,**

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall
INCLUDE = sample.h
OBJ = samople1.o sample2.o

%.o: %.c $(INCLUDE)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

go: $(OBJ)
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```